# WinRT: DataReader.LoadAsync Exception with StreamSocket TCP

Tags: c#, winrt-async

I'm programming a client app on WinRT in C# which connects to several servers by TCP. For the TCP connection I use StreamSocket. The Input and Output Strings are then wrapped in a DataWriter and a DataReader. When I connect to more than one server I get the following exception:
"Operation identifier is not valid"

This is the code of the method:

```
private async void read()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            uint bytesRead = 0;
            try
            {
                bytesRead = await reader.LoadAsync(receiveBufferSize);

                if (bytesRead == 0)
                {
                    OnClientDisconnected(this);
                    return;
                }
                byte[] data = new byte[bytesRead];
                reader.ReadBytes(data);
                if (reader.UnconsumedBufferLength > 0)
                {
                    throw new Exception();
                }

                OnDataRead(this, data);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                if (Error != null)
                    Error(this, ex);
            }

            new System.Threading.ManualResetEvent(false).WaitOne(10);

        }
    }
```

The Stacktrace only shows the reader.LoadAsync(UInt32 count) method as the root of the problem. 
Each ClientInstance is running in an own task and has it's own DataReader and Stream instance. The "receiveBufferSize" is at 8192 Bytes.

Do you have any idea what the error could be?

Comment: Do you mean "When I connect to more than **one** server?"

Comment: @Geoff yes, I'm sorry. I mean "..to more than one server"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think I can answer my question by myself now. The issue was that the LoadAsync method doesn't work so well together with the await/async construct. The method was called by ThreadPool Thread A and then resumed (after await) by ThreadPool Thread B. This constellation threw the Exception. But I can't exactly say why...

With this answer ([How to integrate WinRT asynchronous tasks into existing synchronous libraries?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12822694/how-to-integrate-winrt-asynchronous-tasks-into-existing-synchronous-libraries)) I wrote the LoadAsync method into a synchronous method and now it works because the same thread is calling the method and uses the results of it.

Here is the modified code fragment:

```
IAsyncOperation<uint> taskLoad = reader.LoadAsync(receiveBufferSize);
taskload.AsTask().Wait();
bytesRead = taskLoad.GetResults();
```

Thanks Geoff for bringing me on to the right path with the threads :)
I hope I can help someone who also (will) have this issue.

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me that the likely cause of the exception is this piece [from the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee652610%28v=vs.95%29.aspx):

> When a previous call to LoadAsync is not yet complete.

Reading further down:

> The LoadAsync method can be called only once on the UI thread. The
>   method cannot be called again until after the LoadCompleted event is
>   raised. The LoadCompleted event is raised whether or not the query
>   succeeds.

Then, combine that with [this very thorough answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9898995/55487) on why async/await isn't just pure magic sauce:

> [...]await does not magically cause a synchronous method to run
>   asynchronously. It does not start up a new thread and run the method
>   on the new thread, for example.

So it would appear that the second call to `LoadAsync()` is occurring before the first complete; both are made from the same UI thread.

Comment: thanks for your answer but I think you've looked up the wrong method. The DataReader (with StreamSocket-Stream Input) I'm using is documented here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/BR208119

Comment: Ah, you're right. Given how sparse the correct documentation is, you might want to at least investigate whether running the `LoadAsync` call in another thread will help solve the problem.

Comment: ok I've found a solution now. I made the LoadAsync to be called blocking and not with async/await. I will answer my question as soon as I can. (stackoverflow prevents new users from answering their questions within 8 hours...)