# Receive data from arduino through bluetooth in windows phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-8

i found this  example(https://developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/Windows_Phone_8_communicating_with_Arduino_using_Bluetooth) in my research to develop a bluetooth console to windows phone 8. This example work very well, except for the TERMINATE function. When i call TERMINATE function, the ReceiveMessages function still trying receive data, but there is no more socket available and it generate a system.exception. I tried a lot of workaround, but i dont have enough experience with C#, this is my first APP. Anyone know how can i workaround this situation or have a better example?

i did only 1 modificiation:

```
private async void AppToDevice()
        {
            if (!connected)
            {
                ConnectAppToDeviceButton.Content = "Connecting...";
                PeerFinder.AlternateIdentities["Bluetooth:Paired"] = "";
                var pairedDevices = await PeerFinder.FindAllPeersAsync();

                if (pairedDevices.Count == 0)
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine("No paired devices were found.");
                }
                else
                {
                    foreach (var pairedDevice in pairedDevices)
                    {
                        if (pairedDevice.DisplayName == DeviceName.Text)
                        {
                            connectionManager.Connect(pairedDevice.HostName);
                            ConnectAppToDeviceButton.Content = "Disconnect";
                            DeviceName.IsReadOnly = true;
                            //ConnectAppToDeviceButton.IsEnabled = false;
                            continue;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                connectionManager.Terminate();
                ConnectAppToDeviceButton.Content = "Connect";
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution here:
[WinRT: DataReader.LoadAsync Exception with StreamSocket TCP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16110561/winrt-datareader-loadasync-exception-with-streamsocket-tcp)

I did only a few modifications:

```
public void Terminate()
    {
        try
        {
            if (socket != null)
            {
                taskLoadLength.Cancel();
                taskLoadLength.Close();
                taskLoadMessage.Cancel();
                taskLoadMessage.Close();
                socket.Dispose();
                dataReadWorker.CancelAsync();
                dataReader.Dispose();
                dataWriter.Dispose(); 
                isInicialized = false;   
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(e.Message);
        }
    }

private void ReceiveMessages(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs ev)
    {
        while (true)
        {
            try
            {
                // Read first byte (length of the subsequent message, 255 or less). 
                //uint sizeFieldCount = await dataReader.LoadAsync(1);
                taskLoadLength = dataReader.LoadAsync(1);
                taskLoadLength.AsTask().Wait();
                uint sizeFieldCount = taskLoadLength.GetResults();
                if (sizeFieldCount != 1)
                {
                    // The underlying socket was closed before we were able to read the whole data. 
                    return;
                }
                // Read the message. 
                uint messageLength = dataReader.ReadByte();
                taskLoadMessage = dataReader.LoadAsync(messageLength);
                taskLoadMessage.AsTask().Wait();
                uint actualMessageLength = taskLoadMessage.GetResults();
                //uint actualMessageLength = await dataReader.LoadAsync(messageLength);
                if (messageLength != actualMessageLength)
                {
                    // The underlying socket was closed before we were able to read the whole data. 
                    return;
                }
                // Read the message and process it.
                string message = dataReader.ReadString(actualMessageLength);
                MessageReceived(message);
            }
            catch (AggregateException ae)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ae.Message);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(e.Message);
            }
        }
    }
```